# late 50's early 60's scifi film - Team in a bunker fend off robotic invaders

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a black & white Sci-fi movie about robotic invaders and a team that hides out in a nuclear bunker to invent a weapon to destroy their cathode ray tube controller. Brian notes that the bunker had 3 or 4 levels and a workshop. The team was made up of 3 men and 1 woman. I think she was the daughter of one of the men, a scientist.

Comment: Is "Brian" a typo here?

Comment: Did the robotic invader resemble a gorilla in a diving helmet?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Monster?

Comment: That's the one I was fishing for info about

Comment: @Danny3414: I think it's worthwhile to add it as an answer. It does seem to largely match up.

Answer (score 4):

Robot Monster 1953

Robot Monster tells the story of Moon robot Ro-Man's mission to Earth to destroy humanity.

> He manages to kill all but eight survivors, who have become immune to his death ray.
>
> Ro-Man runs afoul of the Great Guidance, his leader, when he becomes attracted to the human Alice.
> She is the eldest daughter of a surviving scientist, and he refuses to harm her. The Great Guidance must now finish what the Moon robot started

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Robotmonster.jpg